# Need help on extracting data using Xpath in my Python code

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping

**Question 1**

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="preferredContact paragraph">ph:<span preferredcontact="40">(02) 9540 9959</span></div>
```

I am trying to extract that phone number using xpath.

I have tried

```
data['phone'] = c.xpath('.//span[@preferredContact="40"]/text()')
```

and

```
data['phone'] = c.xpath('.//span[contains(@preferredContact,"40")]/text()')
```

Both of them return only null. Can someone show me the code to extract that phone number, please?

**Question 2**

HTML code is

```
<a rel="nofollow" title="View website for Ruth Newman Architect (in new window)" target="_blank" name="listing_website" id="websiteLink40" alreadysentorpevent="false" class="links ext-no-tooltip orpDuplicateEvent" href="/app/redirect?headingCode=27898&amp;productId=473639214&amp;productVersion=1&amp;listingUrl=%2Fnsw%2Fgymea-bay%2Fruth-newman-architect-12781682-listing.html&amp;webSite=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ruthnewman.com.au&amp;pt=w&amp;context=businessTypeSearch&amp;referredBy=YOL&amp;eventType=websiteReferral">www.ruthnewman.com.au
</a>
```

I want to get the link which is located next to the string **webSite=http%3A%2F%2F**. This string is in the href attribute's value. So, in the above example, I want **www.ruthnewman.com.au**. I do not know how to get that using Xpath.

Can someone help out please?

Comment: Spelling error: "preferredcontact" vs. "preferredContact".

Comment: Hey Thanks, that worked! Any help with that second question?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the second question, at first. Let me know if my edited answer addresses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are case-sensitive. For the first question use (no caps):

```
.//span[@preferredcontact='40']/text()
```

For the second question use:

```
substring-before(substring-after(
    .//a[contains(@href, 'webSite=')]/@href, 'webSite=http%3A%2F%2F'), '&')
```

This first selects everything *after* `'webSite=http%3A%2F%2F'` in the attribute, then, using that as the input to `substring-before`, extracts everything *before* the first `&`, which should contain the target string.

Note that in your given examples the `descendant-or-self` (`//`) axis is not really needed. Try to avoid it whenever possible. The flexibility gained comes at the cost of precision and efficiency.

Comment: I dont know why but `substring-before(substring-after(
    .//a[contains(@href, 'webSite=')]/@href, 'webSite=http%3A%2F%2F'), '&')` throws Invalid Syntax error.